# Why isn't the value echoed?

Tags: php

I'm trying to print a value input in the form, but it's not working. If I use GET instead of POST, it works. Why is it so? Is there something wrong?
Here's my code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['sub']) && isset($_POST["numb"])){
echo $_POST["numb"];
}
?>
<body>
    <form name="form" action="">
    <input type="number" name="numb"></input>
    <input type="submit" name="sub"></input>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Add the form method as "post" and use $_POST for the 'sub' instead of request.

Comment: When is REQUEST used?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

Comment: you should use  `$_GET`, `$_POST` or `$_COOKIE` instead of `$_REQUEST` in almost all situations

Comment: I usually use $_REQUEST when I can't determine the request type which is rarely happen.

Comment: it should be very rare not to know the know the request type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the method attribute to your form, it specifies how to send form-data:

```
<form name="form" method="POST">
```

Or you can change `$_POST` to (`$_GET` or `$_REQUEST`). `$_REQUEST` by default contains the contents of `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE`.

Comment: well to use POST you do, you can leave it blank for GET

Comment: Would I need to change REQUEST to POST then? When is REQUEST used?